# What is the standard format of training data for a MLP when the dataset includes various kind of data?

Tags: categorical-data, deep-learning, data-preprocessing, perceptron

I am using a [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing) that includes different kind of data:

1. Real valued variables
2. Binomial categorial variables
3. Multilabel categorical variables

I would like to build a deep multi-layer perceptron using TensorFlow, however I do not know how I could possibly shape the training data in order to be able to feed it to TensorFlow.

In R I would normally encode the categorical variables as factors and the the quantitative variables as real values. But using tensorflow I no longer have this option.

Encoding categorical variables using progressive integers such as:

```
marital status: married -> 0, single -> 1, divorced -> 2, unknown -> 3.
```

seems to be potentially dangerous to me, furthermore it would not work so well with a MLP. I would normaly encode the categorical variables as a "one hot" vector but this would lead to a matrix with inconsistent shape. For instance the factors "default" and "marital status" have different levels and this would lead to a different number of columns in the resulting "one hot" vector and therefore I cannot make a consistent matrix out of it.

What is the standard approach in this case? (or, if you prefer, what options do I have?)

Comment: "For instance the factors "default" and "marital status" have different levels" -> What do you mean?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt sorry, I was using the "R jargon" :) I mean that for marital status you can have three values (see above), for default you would have only 2 values (either yes or no). So in this case, if you encode both variables as a one hot vector, you get a vector of length 4 for marital status and a vector of length 2 for default. This means that you cannot bind those two variables in a matrix..

Comment: "a vector of length 4 for marital status and a vector of length 2" -> Why not    concatenating them into a vector of length 6 instead of a matrix?